# Populate treeview control with hierarchical data from Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, treeview

I am currently using a treeview control from [Treeview Control from JKP](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp). Trying to populate the tree with hierarchical data from an Excel Sheet, I encountered this problem: the tree I populated does not reflect the data. In this picture `AP0004` should be under `TP0002`

[image: Populate a treeview control in VBA]

The code I've tried is this

```
For Each c In Sheet14.Range("A2:A" & Sheet14.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    On Error Resume Next
    'Populate level 1
    Set cRoot = .AddRoot(sKey:=c.Value2, vCaption:=c.Value2)

    Set cExtraNode = cRoot.AddChild("ML_" & c.Value2, "Meilensteine")

    'Populate level 2
    Set cNode = cRoot.AddChild(c.Offset(, 1).Value2, c.Offset(, 1).Value2)

    'Populate level 3
    If cNode.Level = 2 Then Set cNode = cNode.ParentNode

    If Not IsEmpty(c.Offset(, 2).Value2) Then
        Set cNode = cNode.AddChild(c.Offset(, 2).Value2, c.Offset(, 2).Value2)
    End If

    'Populate level 4
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Offset(, 3).Value2) Then
        If cNode.Level = 2 Then
            Set cNode = cNode.AddChild(c.Offset(, 3).Value2, c.Offset(, 3).Value2)
            Set cNode = cNode.ParentNode
        ElseIf cNode.Level = 1 Then
            Set cNode = cNode.Child.AddChild(c.Offset(, 2).Value2, c.Offset(, 2).Value2)
            Set cNode = cNode.Child.AddChild(c.Offset(, 3).Value2, c.Offset(, 3).Value2)
            Set cNode = cNode.ParentNode
        End If
    End If
Next
```

There must be something wrong with my approach here. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it now.I know it's spaghetti code, but for now It works.

For future-people, who may need this

```
lastRow = Sheet14.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' root nodes
For Each c In Sheet14.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    If cRoot Is Nothing Then
        Set cRoot = .AddRoot(sKey:=c.Value2, vCaption:=c.Value2)
        cRoot.Bold = True
        currentRootKey = cRoot.key
        Set cExtraNode = cRoot.AddChild("ML_" & c.Value2, "Meilensteine")
        currentMLKey = cExtraNode.key
    End If
    If c.Value2 <> currentRootKey Then
        Set cRoot = .AddRoot(sKey:=c.Value2, vCaption:=c.Value2)
        cRoot.Bold = True
        currentRootKey = cRoot.key

        Set cExtraNode = cRoot.AddChild("ML_" & c.Value2, "Meilensteine")
        currentMLKey = cExtraNode.key
    End If
Next
' level 1 children
For Each c In Sheet14.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value2) And c.Value2 <> currNodeKey Then
        Set cNode = .Nodes(c.Offset(, -1).Value2)
        Set cNode = cNode.AddChild(c.Value2, c.Value2)
        currNodeKey = cNode.key
    End If
Next
'level 2 children
For Each c In Sheet14.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value2) And c.Value2 <> currNodeKey Then
        Set cNode = .Nodes(c.Offset(, -1).Value2)
        Set cNode = cNode.AddChild(c.Value2, c.Value2)
        currNodeKey = cNode.key
    End If
Next
'level 3 children
For Each c In Sheet14.Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value2) And c.Value2 <> currNodeKey Then
        Set cNode = .Nodes(c.Offset(, -1).Value2)
        Set cNode = cNode.AddChild(c.Value2, c.Value2)
        currNodeKey = cNode.key
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's somewhere around here:

```
Set cNode = cNode.Child.AddChild(c.Offset(, 3).Value2, c.Offset(, 3).Value2)
```

`cNode.Child` simply picks the first child of `cNode`, not the one you want.

Notice how AP003 is the only node under TP002, because it is the case where TP002 is created.

---

General note: The global `On Error Resume Next` might seem elegant to spare you the need of checking if a node already exists, but it will also mask any other errors that might come up.

IMHO a better approach is to always check: does the parent node I need already exist?
If yes, this gets you the node you need to add the child.
If no, create it, and then you have the parent node too.

Comment: Thank you, I tried different approach now and It works.