# Excel Dynamic Grouping/Hierarchy Tool

Tags: excel, dynamic, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-clustering

Let's say I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

Raw Data (for Excel):

```
HouseholdID HouseholdMemberID   Name    AnnualIncome
1   1.1 Man $50,000 
1   1.2 Woman   $50,000 
1   1.3 Boy $2,000 
1   1.4 Girl    $50 
2   2.1 Man $0 
2   2.2 Woman   $125,000 
2   2.3 Girl    $0 
3   3.1 Man $45,000 
3   3.2 Girl    $20 
4   4.1 Man $80,000
```

---

As you can see, there are 4 columns:

1. HouseholdID - this is what I would like the ability to
   roll-up to
2. HouseholdMemberID - this is a unique
   identifier for each record in the dataset (eg. If I am in
   HouseholdID = 1 and I am the 4th member, my unique value would be
   1.4)
3. Name - this is a vanilla name field
4. AnnualIncome (at the HouseholdMemberID level)

---

With this dataset, I would like to have the ability to start with this view (at the HouseholdLevel):

[image]

For example, we can see that Household1 has an AnnualIncome of $102,050, which is calculated by summing the AnnualIncome for each member of HouseholdID = 1:

- Man - $50,000
- Woman - $50,000
- Boy - $2,000
- Girl - $50

---

Additionally, i'd like the ability to be able to show the data as follows:

[image]

...to be able to see how each Household Member contributes to the AnnualIncome of the Household.

---

For the purposes of this example, I used Grouping in Excel to manually accomplish this task; however, I would like to make use of dynamic grouping. In other words, i'd like to be able to import a dataset that has these identical columns each month, but with varying numbers of households (and household members). How can I do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try PivotTables group your data by Households and calculate total Income. To group/resume data, PivotTables in Excel is exactly what you need. The cool thing is that your Pivot Table can be linked to a normal table where you update your data, and then your Pivot Table will update with the data if you want :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate treeview control with hierarchical data from Excel Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039831/populate-treeview-control-with-hierarchical-data-from-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PivotTables. My normal data is in a normal table:
[image]

And with PivotTables. I resume the data exactly as you need:

[image]

**UPDATE ANSWER.** With an additional click. I can use also the Field NAME so i get more data as you want. It just takes about 0.00000003 seconds to do it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Foxfire, the only limitation of this approach that I see is in your second image, once you have HouseholdID1, HouseholdID2, HouseholdID3, HouseholdID4, you can't click on HouseholdID1 to see Man, Woman, Boy, and Girl's Income, as shown in the last image of my question posting (Ideally, I would be able to toggle from the Household View and the Household Member View with a single click for each Household ID). Any further help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should check all you can do with Pivot Tables. I Posted only 1 image of what you want. but the data shown depends on how you set your pivot table. I updated my answer with another image. Is just same pivot table with another field. I did this with exactly 1 clic more. I mean, presenting data with Pivot Tables is really easy and fast.

Comment: Thanks again Foxfire - this gave me a lot of ideas - although this solution with my large dataset exceeds Excel's file size limits when used in a pivot table with extensive conditional formatting...I will seek an alternative software solution to fulfill these needs.

Comment: @MattReichenbach I'm curious about your data size. Excel's Limits are high, if you know how to handle it. Just an example, in my job we got some daily routines that work with datasets that are more than 500.000 rows and even 1000 columns. Conditional Formating may affect performance but not that much, but what does indeed affects size limits and performance is formatting too much cells. It's much better to work on raw data and use some conditional formats instead of formating a complete column applying, for example, Text format. May I know what kind of data you work with?

Comment: For the purposes of this particular use case, the dataset is between 100-200k rows with ~100 columns...so much smaller than your usual - the tool that I would like to build would have the hierarchy as described above, with 20+ Slicers, and conditional formatting on 40+ columns (within the pivot table)...it starts getting sluggish pretty early on...thoughts or additional questions?

Comment: @MattReichenbach I would advice you to make sure all your data are raw data. I mean, I would delete ALL format in ALL cells, and then I would apply the format only in Pivot Tables, so Excel would improve performance. But I don't know what kind of data you manage, so not sure if this solution would work. My data is 95% numbers, so it works for me.

Comment: The data is all raw (no vlookups, no formatting, no calcs, etc)...I pull data from SQL and paste into Excel directly, then I use a pivot table on that data